# Googleapis: "failed to load external entity"

Tags: php, api, google-maps

Since 2 days we have problems with Google API Maps Geocode.
We don't have response with this PHP call:

```
$base_url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=48.000,2.0000&key=MyServerKey";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($base_url);
```

Response:

*PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=....*

The call works when we call it from another IP.
We don't have made change on the PHP code since a lot of month...

Have you an idea from the problem?
Can Google blacklist IPs? There is no indication in Google Cloud Platform about a problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: google can certainly blacklist ip addresses - if it works from one ip but not another that would suggest they have blocked it

Comment: But why... we pay about 50$ per month for quota.

Comment: And we can not have technical support...

Comment: Check if this might be related to Google Maps API root CA migration described in this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67842936. Does your server has all required by Google root certificates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in discussion with Google support....
It seems to be an IPV6 problem.

When i made a "wget" to maps.googleapis.com, i have a timout but if I have to use an ip v4, it works.

I will put the result when I have the solution...